# how to save each two successive frames in webgl

Tags: webgl

I know how to render an object using a rotation matrix R1. but what i want to know is how i save the resulting frame into a texture, then rotate this object using the mouse and saving the second frame into another texture. How can i do this in webgl?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way is to make a new texture and call`gl.copyTexImage2D` which copies from the canvas (or current framebuffer) into a texture. Another way is to attach a texture to a framebuffer and render directly into that framebuffer

Comment: yes, but when i rotate the object using the mouse (handle mouse mouve function), the values stored in the framebuffer will be crashed and replaced by the new values. I want keep the values of each frame in a texture. my code run at 60 fps how  can i limit the duration between two frames to minimize the number of frames and store them into textures